# Why does the first Firebase call from the server take much longer to return than subsequent calls?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions

**Problem**

First call to Firebase from a server takes ~15 - 20X longer than subsequent calls. While this is not a problem for a conventional server calling upon Firebase, it may cause issues with a server-less architecture leveraging Amazon Lambda/ Google Cloud Functions.

**Questions**

- Why is the first call so much slower? Is it due to authentication?
- Are there any workarounds?
- Is it practical to do some user-initiated computation of data on Firebase DB using Amazon Lambda/ Google Cloud Functions and return the results to the client within 1 - 2 seconds?

**Context**

I am planning on using a server-less architecture with Firebase as the repository of my data and Amazon Lambda/ Cloud Functions augmenting Firebase with some server-side computation, e.g. searching for other users. I intend to trigger the functions via HTTP requests from my client.

One concern that I had was the large time taken by the first call to Firebase from the server. While testing some server-side code on my laptop, the first listener returns back in 6s! Subsequent calls return in 300 - 400ms. The dataset is very small (2 - 3 key value pairs) and I also tested by swapping the observers.

In comparison, a call to the Google Maps API from my laptop takes about 400ms to return.

I realise that response times would be considerably faster from a server. Still a factor of 15 - 20X on the first call is disconcerting.

Comment: The initial call will need to build up the HTTP connection, upgrade it to web sockets and indeed do a mutli-roundtrip authentication handshake. Subsequent loading data from the database only has to transfer the request, get the data from disk (potentially) and transfer it back. But without seeing a concrete implementation, it'll be hard to say more.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR:** You're noticing something that's known/expected, though we will shave the penalty down as GA approaches. Some improvements will come sooner than later.

Cloud Functions for Firebase team member here. We are able to offer Cloud Functions at a competitive price by "scaling to zero" (shutting down all instances) after sustained lack of load. When a request comes in and you have no available instances, Cloud Functions creates one for you on demand. This is obviously slower than hitting an active server and is something we call a "cold start". Cold starts are part of the reality of "serverless" architecture, but we have many people working on ways to reduce the penalty dramatically.

There's another case that I've recently started calling a "lukewarm" start. After a deploy, the Cloud Function instance has been created, but your application still has warmup work to do like establishing a connection to the Firebase Realtime Database. Part of this *is* authentication, as you've suggested. We have detected a slowdown here that will be fixed next week. After that, you'll still have to pay for SSL + Firebase handshakes. Try measuring this latency; it's not clear how much we'll be able to circumvent it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Frank!! Read up on how firebase establishes web-socket connections.

To add to Frank's answer, the initial handshake causes the delay in the first pull. The approach drastically speeds up subsequent data pulls. While testing on an Amazon Lambda instance running on a US-west coast server. The response times were: 1) **First pull: 1.6 - 2.3s** 2) **Subsequent pulls: 60 - 100ms**. The dataset itself was extremely small, so one can assume that these time periods are simply for server-to-server communications. Takeaways:

- Amazon Lambda instances can be triggered via an API gateway for non time-critical computations but is not the ideal solution for real-time computations on Firebase data such as returning search results (unless there is a way to guarantee persisting the handshake over instances - not from what I've read)
- For time critical computations, I am going for running EC2/ GAE instances leveraging Firebase Queue. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue. The approach is more involved than firing lambda instances, but would return results faster (because of avoiding the handshake for every task).